# Factor group of a finite cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

> Prove that
>    $$\mathbb Z_m/\langle \overline{n}\rangle \cong\mathbb Z_{\text{gcd}(m,n)}.$$
>   for any $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$.

For this, I know I must show that in $\mathbb Z_m$, $\langle \overline{n} \rangle$ and $\langle \text{gcd}(m,n)\rangle$ are the same ideal, but I'm not sure how I could possibly show that. Any suggestions?

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Consider  the projection $\Bbb Z_m \to \Bbb Z_{gcd(m,n)}$ and the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: So I want to show that it maps one-to-one and onto, correct?

Comment: Yes for the 'onto', no for the 'one-to-one', note that if $d = gcd(m,n)$, then $d$ projects to $0$.

Comment: How do I show that it is onto? I know that it maps onto S provided its image is all of S, but I don't know how to prove this for a problem like this.